# Substitute data in createReadStream in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm not really sure I'm asking the right question here... so please don't attack me.

I'm creating my own asynchronous callback library for a type of tracking implementation. The user must install a piece of code on their site that contains a unique account number. Think Google Analytics.

The library call reaches out to my node server and passes along the account id in the query parameter.

Node responds with the analytics library so various tracking functions can be called on the user's site.

My question is, how can I modify my static tracking library that gets streamed back to the user's page based on the query parameter? For instance, once the account ID is read off the query string, I do a DB look-up to find some values in the library that are specific to that user and would like to modify particular functions in my library appropriately.

I'm reading a static file off my local server with:
    fs.createReadStream("./file.js");

How can I modify that file to substitute certain values within for others?

Or should I be reading the file in to an in-memory object at startup and then simply writing out modified data via the response object?

Comment: I would recommend doing what you suggested at the end - reading the file into memory, modifying there, and then sending out the modified file

Comment: Do you mean read the file in to memory at every request, or just once and modifying it on response?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use *eco* or *ejs* templates for this, but for just to have an idea or if you prefer to make this yourself, I think you should make a template based on your `file.js` and then write user specific parts of the code with the corersponding data using a set of regular expressions.

For example:

***template.js***

```javascript
var get_user = function () {
  return "Hi %%USER_NAME%%"
}
```

then req.send()` the content of *template.js* replaced something like this:

```javascript
var result = cached_template_data;
if (!result) {
  fs.readFile("./template.js", function (err, data) {
    result = cached_template_data = data;
    if (!err) {
      result = result.replace(/%%USER_NAME%%/g, user.name)
      res.send(result);
    } else {
      // Big oops
      res.send({error:true}, 500);
    }
  })
} else {
  result = result.replace(/%%USER_NAME%%/g, user.name)
  res.send(result);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Consider caching whenever possible by the way...

Comment: I like this, but isn't there some inherent "wrong way of doing things" reading the file in to memory for every response and what the createReadStream was meant to fix?

Comment: The file should only be read once ( or every time the template file is modified ) and it's content is replacing for each request, caching the result for each user and only rebuilding the result on user-data's update for better performance.

Comment: modified example to add caching of template content. But remember, this is just to **illustrate** how could it be done. You don't need to reinvent the wheel, use [*eco*](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) or [*ejs*](http://embeddedjs.com/) or any other cool template engine.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use template engines. Too much overhead and other features I don't need.

Another question if you're going to cache for each user: You're now storing N number of user's versions of the files in memory.. seems like a bad idea, no?

BTW, thanks for your attention! Really appreciate this discussion.